# Naming a list of imported and varying .CSV files in a loop

Tags: r

I am importing a number of .CSV files using:

```
folder <- paste("D:/Folder/", sep = "")
file_list <- list.files(path=folder, pattern="*.csv")
for (i in 1:length(file_list)){assign(file_list[i], read.csv(paste(folder, file_list[i],sep=''), header = TRUE))}
```

The number of .CSV files may vary. So I need to Name those files from A to Z because I need to trim a few columns using

```
A =  select(A, Emp, Pro,Cust, Role) #using Dplyr package
```

and the merge those varying files using "merge"

The issue is: **As those files will vary, using "Select" and "Merge" will not be possible which requires DataSet name.**

Comment: `paste("D:/Folder/", sep = "")` does nothing at all, it's the same as just `"D:/Folder/"`.

Comment: Yes, I had variable folders so can be used it in that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this to assign variables to letters in the global environment:

```
for (i in 1:length(file_list)){assign(letters[i], read.csv(paste(folder, file_list[i],sep=''), header = TRUE), .GlobalEnv)}
```

If you try to `assign(file_list[i], ...)` you are just basically replacing `file_list` with the data which doesn't seem to be what you want.